# Swapping adjacent numbers in arrays

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

Here's the problem: Write a method called swapPairs that accepts an array of integers and swaps the elements at adjacent indexes.  That is, elements 0 and 1 are swapped, elements 2 and 3 are swapped, and so on.  If the array has an odd length, the final element should be left unmodified.  For example, the list {10,20,30,40,50} should become {20,10,40,30,50} after a call to your method.

Write method printArray that is passed an array and will print out each element.
Use this method to print the array modified by swapPairs.

This is my code:

```
public static void swapPairs(int[] a){
    int len=a.length;
        if(len%2 ==0){
            for(int i=0; i<len; i=i+2){
                a[i]=a[i+1];
                a[i+1]=a[i];
                int[] b={a[i]+a[i+1]};
            }   
        }
        if(len%2 !=0){
            for(int j=0; j<len; j=j+2){
                a[j]=a[j+1];
                a[j+1]=a[j];
                a[len-1]=a[len-1];
                int[] b={a[j]+a[j+1]+a[len-1]};
            }
        }   
}
public static void printArray(int[] a){
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

However, what it returns is [I@2a139a55

Comment: Your not swapping anything, because in your first loop you overwrite a[I] then use a[I] to assign to the element you copied to a[I], you need a temporary variable to store the contents of a[I] before the assignment then use the temporary variable to assign to a[I+1].

Comment: At first you write `if(len%2 ==0)`. Later you write `if (len%2 !=0)`. Why not only write `else` there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After almost breaking my computer several times, here's the actual working code:

```
public static void swapPairs(int[] a){
    int len=a.length;
        if(len%2 ==0){
            for(int i=0; i<len; i=i+2){
                int c=a[i]+a[i+1];
                a[i]=c-a[i];
                a[i+1]=c-a[i+1];
            }   
        }
        if(len%2 !=0){
            for(int j=0; j<len-1; j=j+2){
                int c=a[j]+a[j+1];
                a[j]=c-a[j];
                a[j+1]=c-a[j+1];
            }   
            a[len-1]=a[len-1];
        }   
}
public static void printArray(int[] a){
    int len=a.length;
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
        System.out.print(a[i]+" ");
}
```

Comment: This solution is a bit complicated

Answer (score 2):

What you need to print is `Arrays.toString(a)`

Now, you are just printing the Hashcode of your Array object

Answer (score 1):

First, your swap method could be simplified. Add both numbers together, and then subtract each from the sum (to get the other number). Something like,

```
public static void swapPairs(int[] a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i += 2) {
        int c = a[i] + a[i + 1];
        a[i] = c - a[i];
        a[i + 1] = c - a[i + 1];
    }
}
```

Then you could use [`Arrays.toString(int[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-int:A-) to get a `String`. Like,

```
public static void printArray(int[] a) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
}
```

I tested the above like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] t = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    printArray(t);
    swapPairs(t);
    printArray(t);
}
```

And I got

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[2, 1, 4, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void swapPairs(int[] arr){
    int length = arr.length%2 == 0? arr.length : arr.length-1;

    for(int i=0; i<length; i=i+2) {
        int temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] =     arr[i+1];
        arr[i+1] = temp;
    }
    // print the array
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void swapPairs(int[] a){
        int len = a.length - a.length % 2; // if len is odd, remove 1
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
            int temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[i + 1];
            a[i + 1] = temp;
        }
    }
    
    public static void printArray(int[] a){
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] iArr1 = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
        int[] iArr2 = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60};
        swapPairs(iArr1);
        swapPairs(iArr2);
        printArray(iArr1); // [20, 10, 40, 30, 50]
        printArray(iArr2); // [20, 10, 40, 30, 60, 50]
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
final int[] number = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i = i + 2) {
        if (i > number.length - 2) {
            break;
        }
        temp = number[i];
        number[i] = number[i + 1];
        number[i + 1] = temp;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < number.length; j++) {
        System.out.print(number[j]);
    }
```

Comment: Add some explainatins or comment to your answer like what you change and why you did this.

Comment: Why do you use the `for` condition ì < number.length` and later in that loop the `if` condition `i > number.length - 2`?

Answer (score -1):

import java.util.Scanner;
public class SwapEveryPair {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scn.nextInt();
    int[] arr = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = scn.nextInt();

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < (arr.length - 1); i += 2) {
        int temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
        arr[i + 1] = temp;
    }
    for(int i=0; i< arr.length; i++){
        System.out.println(" " + arr[i]);
    }
}
}``
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Before posting an answer you should ask yourself these fundamental questions: | 
`Is my answer showing a different solution to all the other answers?`(the swap and print functionality are similar to multiple other answers) | 
`Is an answer still relevant to the community?`(the question was asked 5 years ago) | 
`Is every part of my answer relevant to the question?`(You use a scanner to read the array while the OP specifically said "a method […] that accepts an array of integers". Therefor the method of getting that array is irrelevant for the question.)

Answer (score -2):

I think this should work,

```
public static void swapAlternate(int[] input){
 for(int i=0;i<input.length - 1; i+=2){
        int temp = input[i];
        input[i] = input[i+1];
        input[i+1] = temp;
    }
}
```